# How to notify event subscriber

Tags: c#, events

In my last job interview I was asked how to implement a class which exposes an event and notifies new event subscribers at the moment they subscribe to that event.

In other words, a class exposes an event to inform subscribers when a data source is updated; many other classes can subscribe to the event at any point in time. When a class subscribes to the event it must be notified to get latest version of data stored into the data source, but other classes must not be notified (they are already up to date).

They have suggested me to override the addHandler method, but how do I notify only the new subscriber?

Is there a feature of the .net I'm not aware of or do I need to define a method in the subscriber class to be called when adding to handler (some kind observer pattern)?

EDIT: i think i'm not been clear, so i'll try to explain it in another way. 
Suppose i've an observer pattern. When a new observer subscribe the subject it gets immediatly updated with lastest datasource values by subject .Later, when somethnig inside the datasource will change, the subject will notify all registered observers as usual. I'm been asked how to make this with .net events

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your terminology is wooly - what do you mean by "it must be activated"? Do you mean the event handler has to be called once at the point of subscription? If so, that sounds something like:

```
private EventHandler foo;

public event EventHandler Foo 
{
    add
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            value(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        foo += value;
    }

    remove
    {
        foo -= value;
    }
}
```

It's a pretty odd design though.

If that isn't what you're after, please try to clarify.

See my [article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Is't there situation when a subscriber adds to an event they immediately need to provide with the latest value. It that case can't this pattern be useful.

Comment: In my understanding , they wanted to know how to notify only the last event subscriber, i've suggested to raise the event at any new subscription, they have replied this way i would have notified all subscribers (and forgive my bad english, i've replaced "activated" with "notified" )

Comment: @Stefano: actualy no. This will only raise it on the new delegate, that is stored in value. I would also question if it is good design. I dont really expect event to be raised before asigning even ends. It would be better to let client pull the new informating, when it needs to before he starts listening to events.